Git: retrieving the name of the original name of a document
I changed the name of an old file I committed several days ago. Now I need the name of that original document for a board meeting presentation. If it makes any difference, I'm on iMac OSX using iTerm2.
I have already tried the following commands without any luck. I'm expecting to see the actual original, user-end filename. Example of expected result: "01_Introduction_Statistics.pages"
git log 
git log --pretty=oneline --graph --name-status
git show --pretty=oneline --graph --name-status
git diff --name-only
git svn log -v
git show --[=pretty<format>]
git show --oneline
git log --raw
git show --name-only

**git blame -f, --show-name       show original filename (Default: auto)

This last one appears to provide what I need, but I'm not sure how to use it. I keep getting "error: unknown option `-,'" I have no idea what that means.
I have already tried
git blame -f, --show-name <hash code>
It returns an error. I'm lost and confused.

remove the comma after git blame -f,

Thanks! I tried the following, but no luck.
git blame -f --show-name d9f0e29d33065468f29efdc60ab361445d94b1a4
fatal: no such path 'd9f0e29d33065468f29efdc60ab361445d94b1a4' in HEAD

What is d9f0e29d33065468f29efdc60ab361445d94b1a4?

You could try git log --all --summary | grep -E 'rename|file move|move', which lists only commit messages that indicate renames (if you remember the commit message(s) and you use a recurring pattern for such renames). If you have an idea about the directory where the file might have originally been located, you can search that specific directory using the --follow option: git log --follow -- <directory_name>.

If you have a file and you want to know when it was renamed...
git log --follow --summary --format= <filename>

--follow will continue listing history through renames. --format= suppresses the usual output. --summary shows when the file was created, renamed, or its permissions changed.
$ git log --follow --summary -w --format= baz
 rename bar => baz (100%)
 rename foo => bar (100%)
 create mode 100644 foo

The original name of this file was foo. It was renamed to bar with no content changes. Then renamed again to baz with no content changes.

Note: Git does not track renames. Instead it uses heuristics to look for similar files. A simple git mv like in the history above is easy for Git to follow. However, if you rename a file and alter it in one commit, Git might not be able to follow the rename. It depends on how much was altered and how hard you tell Git to look.
By default it looks for files with at least 50% similarity. You can affect this with -M and -l.
For example, here I git mv baz blat and also added a line and made some whitespace changes.
commit 3c3240d16866a91b499fe17d478b82277c83aded
Author: Michael G. Schwern <schwern@pobox.com>
Date:   Fri May 10 12:22:59 2024 -0700

    mv baz blat, add this

diff --git a/baz b/blat
similarity index 37%
rename from baz
rename to blat
index dfa74aa..43b1a69 100644
--- a/baz
+++ b/blat
@@ -1,4 +1,7 @@
 this
+that
+
 other
-thing
+
+   thing  

This resulted in a similarity threshold below 50%. I need to lower Git's standards for looking for renames to 30%.
$ git log --follow --summary --format= blat
 create mode 100644 blat

$ git log --follow --summary --format= -M.3 blat
 rename baz => blat (37%)
 rename bar => baz (100%)
 rename foo => bar (100%)
 create mode 100644 foo

Because this is a heuristic, Git can get it wrong. You still need to verify.
For this reason, if you need to rename a file and then change a significant portion of the file (and if it's a very small file any change can be significant) it's good practice to rename in one commit and alter in another, even if this results in a broken commit.

Wow! Excellent! All this is very useful. I was able to track the entire renaming cycle for a set of the files in question. Wonderful tips and advice! Thanks, @Schwern!

Try git log --follow <current_file_name>.
This should give history of the file even if it changed names.

Thanks! This command is also good. It returns the history of a filename in hash code and not the actual filename directly. I can still work with it, though and plug in the hash code into the command:
git show --name-only ec391792f5a16ab350b20 and that returns the filename in English.

@Chexpeare Add --stat to show the filename and renames. git log --follow --stat <current filename>. The original filename is the last (oldest) one.

in git blame command -f flag is an alias for --show-name, reference.
So, you should use either of them, not both.
You seem to be using commit hash on your git blame command, use the filename of the current file instead:
git blame -f {currentFilename}


I finally got it! I used:
git show --name-only ec391792f5a16ab350b20c9b2626425c4803cff1
The command returned the name of the file in question. Thanks!

This will only work if there are lines unchanged from before the file was renamed.

Thanks to @mkrieger1, @Christian, @Hujaakbar and @jj2f1, I'm able to combine their suggestions with the additional following git command and retrieve the full filename with extension in English:
git show --name-only <hash code>
